# Optimizing summing/grouping query with millions of rows on MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table with nearly 4.000.000 rows containing income transactions of more than 100.000 employees.

There are three columns relevant in it, which are:

- **Employee ID** *[VARCHAR and INDEX]* (not unique since one employee gets more than one income);
- **Type of Income** *[also VARCHAR and INDEX]*
- **Value of the Income** *[Decimal; 10,2]*

What I was looking to do seems to be very simple to me. I wanted to sum all the income occurrences grouping by each employee, filtering by one type.
For that, I was using the following code:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(`value`) AS `SumofValue`,
    `type`,
    `EmployeeID`
FROM
    `Revenue`
GROUP BY `EmployeeID`
HAVING `type` = 'X'
```

And the result was supposed to be something like this:

```
  SUM        TYPE     EMPLOYEE ID
 R$ 250,00  X   250000008377
 R$ 5.000,00    X   250000004321
 R$ 3.200,00    X   250000005432
 R$ 1.600,00    X   250000008765
....
```

However, this is taking a long time. I decide to use the LIMIT command to limit the results just to 1.000 rows and it is working, but if i want to do for the whole table, it would take approximately 1 hous according to my projections. This seems to be way too much time for something that does not look sooooo demandable to me (but i'm assuming i'm probably wrong). Not only that, but this is just the first step on an even more complex query that i intend to run in the future, in which i will group also by Employer ID, aside with Employee ID (one person can get income from more than one employer).

Is there any way to optimize this? Is there anything wrong with my code? Is there any secret path to increase the speed of this operation? Should I index the column of the value of the income as well? If this is a MySQL limitation, is there any option that could handle this better?
I would really appreaciate any help.

Thanks in advance

DISCLOSURE: This is a open government database. All this data is lawfully open to the public.

Comment: A few things come to mind: Make your EmployeeID an integer instead of a varchar, and have an index on `(EmployeeIdD, type)` (Possibly even as your primary key for the table if that's a unique tuple). Looking at the query plan before and after would be useful too.

Comment: Use WHERE instead of HAVING. It's also good practice to include alll non-aggregated columns from the select in the group by

Comment: Are you suggesting that employee 01234 and 1234 are different people? That seems highly unlikely, and a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Have you checked the execution plan to see whether proper indices are used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, phrase the query using `WHERE`, rather than `HAVING` -- filter *before* doing the aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(`value`) AS `SumofValue`,
       MAX(type) as type,
       EmployeeID
FROM Revenue r
WHERE `type` = 'X'
GROUP BY EmployeeID;
```

Next, try using this index:  `(type, EmployeeId, value)`.  At the very least, this is a covering index for the query.  MySQL (depending on the version) might be smart enough to use it for the aggregation as well.

Comment: I just switched from HAVING to WHERE and the query was done in less than a minute. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

As per your defined schema, Why you are using VARCHAR datatype for Employee ID and Type.
You can create reference table for Type with 1-->X, 2-->Y...So basically integer reference will be for type in transaction table.
Just create one dummy table with below one and execute your same query which was taking hour. Even you will see major change in execution plan as well.

```
CREATE TABLE test_transaction
(
Employee_ID BIGINT,
Type SMALLINT,
Income DECIMAL(10,2)
)
```

Create separate index on Employee_ID and Type column.
khotina

Comment: The Employee ID can't be INT because it might start with a "0" and that "0" makes a difference to differ each one. I believe MySQL will ignore the zero if i turn it into int, right? But the tip about the type is a good one, I'll try it out. Thanks!

Comment: I can help to resolve your "0" prefix problem. you can use auto incremental integer column in your employee table and use that integer reference in transaction table.

Comment: Why a separate index?

Comment: Let's I have Query with "Select * from test_transaction where Employee_ID = ?". No such conditions on "Type" column then that index will not get seek.